# What algorithms should I experiment with to try and classify these PDFs?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, classification

We are crawling and downloading lots of companies' PDFs and trying to pick out the ones that are Annual Reports. Such reports can be downloaded from most companies' investor-relations pages.

The PDFs are scanned and the database is populated with, among other things, the:

- Title
- Contents (full text)
- Page count
- Word count
- Orientation
- First line

Using this data we are checking for the obvious phrases such as:

- Annual report
- Financial statement
- Quarterly report
- Interim report

Then recording the frequency of these phrases and others. So far we have around 350,000 PDFs to scan and a training set of 4,000 documents that have been manually classified as either a report or not.

We are experimenting with a number of different approaches including Bayesian classifiers and weighting the different factors available. We are building the classifier in Ruby. My question is: if you were thinking about this problem, where would you start?

Comment: Thanks for changing the formatting Sergio ;)

Comment: No problem. In future make sure your post looks pretty before hitting "Submit" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try a quick and basic approach first to form a baseline, which may be good enough for your purposes.  Here is one such approach:

Scan all pdfs and form the vocabulary which is a numbered list of all words that occur in any document.

Create a feature vector from this vocabulary for each document by counting the word frequency of each word (all words, dont bother hand picking them).  Feature i of document j, is the number of times word i appears in document j.

Then exponentiate features by word importance, which is the opposite of how often the word occurs in all documents.  (ie The more often the word occurs in all documents (eg "the") the less information it contains.)

Then use a unsupervised clustering algorithm such as k-means to cluster the documents.  You initialize by randomly placing k cluster centroids, assign the nearest documents to them, then move the centroids to the average of the documents assigned to them, then repeat the last two steps until convergence.

Then find the cluster that contains annual reports by using a few hand labeled examples.

Adjust the number of clusters with a cross validation set until the accuracy on the cross validation set is high.

Then finally test on a held out test set.  If this is low come back.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write out your thoughts. Really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For my dissertation a few years back I did something similar, but with digitised lecture slides and exam papers.  One of the nicest books I came across for a good broad overview of search engines, search algorithms, and determining the effectiveness of the search was:

Search Engines: Information Retrieval in Practice, W. Bruce Croft, Donald Metzler, Trevor Strohman

There are some sample chapters in the publishers website which will tell you if the book's for you or not: [pearsonhighered.com](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/croft1epreview/index.html)

Hope that helps.